# How to show custom locations in google map in flutter?

Tags: android, google-maps, flutter, android-mapview

I have some locations stored in firebase and when the user wants the location it should display those locations in Google map. how can I show those locations in google map that is integrated with my flutter app?

Answer (score 1):

It depend if you want only move camera to wanted location or if you want to display location on map using Marker.
Either way, you will need to get these locations from firebase to your app.

For adding Markers to your map follow these [guidlines](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/google-maps-in-flutter/#5). If you want only changing camera position try method `animateCamera()` [GoogleMapController](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/google_maps_flutter/GoogleMapController-class.html).